# Use user_meta in wordpress newsletter template

Tags: php, wordpress, newsletter

Is there any wordpress newsletter plugin that allows sending a customized email to each user in the system, using their metadata (i.e user_meta)?

I'm trying to use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/newsletter/, and I saw in the default templates that use some predefined variables like

- {name}
- {email}
- {unsubscribe_url}

Those variables change for each email sended, according to the receiving user.

Any idea if is there any way to use `$user_ID` and `get_user_meta(...)`?

If it's not possible, are there any newsletter plugin that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a plugin to do that

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/personal-newsletter/